# Add count of duplicate values to Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I don´t want to remove the duplicate values, I want to get the articles_id duplicates and sum their quantity values, for example, this is my collection:

```
Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => CartLine {#294 ▼
      +quantity: 2
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
    }
    1 => CartLine {#296 ▼
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
    }
    2 => CartLine {#298 ▼
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1378
      +article_name: "JARRA CERVEZA ALEMANA"

    }
  ]
}
```

And I want get this result:

```
Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => CartLine {#294 ▼
      +quantity: 3 //sum total quantity of the duplicates elements with same article_id
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
    }
    1 => CartLine {#296 ▼
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 3
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
    }
    2 => CartLine {#298 ▼
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1378
      +article_name: "JARRA CERVEZA ALEMANA"

    }
  ]
}
```

I want sum the quantities of the duplicate elements and set the quantity property with the sum in these elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$collection->groupBy('article_id')->flatMap(function ($items) {

    $quantity = $items->sum('quantity');

    return $items->map(function ($item) use ($quantity) {

        $item->quantity = $quantity;

        return $item;

    });

});
```

Obviously, change `$collection` to be whatever you've called the variable that holds your collection.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 18):

I know this answer was already accepted, but I just found this StackOverflow post when I was searching for the same thing.  What I ended up doing was the following.

```
$users = Users::all();
$usersUnique = $users->unique('id');
$usersDupes = $users->diff($usersUnique);

dd($users, $usersUnique, $usersDupes);
```

I only needed mine for a one time purpose so I am not sure how performant this would be if you need to use it on production page.

Comment: This is incorrect. unique() method will provide ALL unique ids, removing the duplicates, so the diff of the unique collection with the original collection will always be empty.

Comment: This comment is incorrect.. If the original collection is different than the unique one then by definition the diff will not be empty. The diff is `original->diff(unique)`, which is the correct way and what this answer gives and not the other way around (Which would indeed give an empty result)

Answer (score 15):

Another one solution to obtain grouped duplicates:

```
    $collection = collect([
        [
            'name' => 'aa',
            'value' => 22
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'bb',
            'value' => 22
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'cc',
            'value' => 11
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'bb',
            'value' => 33
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'bb',
            'value' => 33
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'bb',
            'value' => 33
        ],
    ]);

    $groupedByValue = $collection->groupBy('value');

    $dupes = $groupedByValue->filter(function (Collection $groups) {
        return $groups->count() > 1;
    });
```

Output:

```
array:2 [▼
  22 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "aa"
      "value" => 22
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "bb"
      "value" => 22
    ]
  ]
  33 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "bb"
      "value" => 33
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "bb"
      "value" => 33
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "bb"
      "value" => 33
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Great example, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best way is:

```
$collectionA = collect(..some articles)->pluck('article_id');
$collectionB = collect(..another articles)->pluck('article_id');

$duplicates = $collectionA->merge($collectionB)->duplicates();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datas = ($datas)->map(function ($data) use ($datas) {
        $sum = $datas->where('article_id', $data['article_id'])->sum('quantity');
        $data['quantity'] = $sum;
        return $data;
    })->toArray();
```