# produce a new array or collection based on certain condition

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

can anyone help me with this query of duplication? how can i produce a new array or collection based on certain condition that matches and keep other records as same. e.g in the following array, i want to move all duplication, which start, end date and provider is same?

```
 $array=[
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 4,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-08',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 5,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-08',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 6,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-09',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-10',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
        ];
```

expected output, the duplicate means, this is kind of same ticket, provided by different providers, so i need to have them together

```
$expectedArray = [
        'duplicates' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 4,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
        ],
        'duplicates' => [
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-08',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 5,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-08',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
        ],
        [
                'id' => 6,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-09',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-10',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889951/4357891. Consider using that accepted answer and modifying the map function to group your duplicates into a `duplicates` array key.

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

```
 $array = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'start_date' => '2022-04-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'provider' => 'abc'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'start_date' => '2022-05-08',
                'end_date' => '2022-06-08',
                'provider' => 'xyz'
            ],
        ];
        
       foreach ($array as $key => &$entry) {
          if($entry['provider']=='abc'){ $expectedArray[0]['duplicates'][$key] = $entry;}else{ $expectedArray[] = $entry;}
           
        }
       
        print_r($expectedArray);
```

Comment: I have updated my question for better clarity. thanks